# using recursion to print out values of a BST - javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand recursion better in Javascript with this code for a BST. I can print out a BST's values with two methods using recursion, but I can't figure out how to do it all in one method.

how can I combine

```js
BinarySearchTree.prototype.dfs = function(node) {
  if (node) {
    console.log(node.val);
    this.dfs(node.left);
    this.dfs(node.right);
  }
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.depthFirstTraversal = function() {
  let current = this.root;
  this.dfs(current);
}
```

into one function? I've been trying

```js
BinarySearchTree.prototype.sameFunction = function(node = null) {
    // if node is null use this.root
    let current = node || this.root;
 
    if (current) {
        console.log(current.val);
        this.sameFunction(current.left);
        this.sameFunction(current.right);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rj2tyd4L/

Comment: Why? Two methods are much better here than one, because there's a clear separation of concerns: the main method applies to the whole tree, the helper method - to a particular node.

Comment: I agree. But as a more general question to learn recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a second argument `isRoot` with it's default value set to `true`?

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.sameFunction = function(node = null, isRoot = true) {
  let current = isRoot ? this.root : node;
  if (current) {
    console.log(current.val);
    this.sameFunction(current.left, false);
    this.sameFunction(current.right, false);
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fez1jtsx/

This makes `tree.sameFunction()` equivalent to calling `tree.depthFirstTraversal()`

Comment: thanks. any idea why this doesn't work when I make it a class method? http://jsfiddle.net/n8ea7ou2/

Comment: @totalnoob you missed the `if` statement: `if (current) {...}`.